# How to crop large image in small form without trimming before crop?

Tags: php, jquery, crop, jcrop

Does someone knows the image-crop which correctly works with the 'dynamically changed in the CSS image size (I mean width and height)'?

All image-crops works fine if there is original image size (for example size: 400px x 400px) and width:100%;

But if show to user picture with sizes 1500px x 1500px and make it smaller just with css to 100px x 100px (because 1500px - usually to much for screen and looks not pretty) - in this case image-croppers what i saw before issued an error or makes a thumbnail with initial values (top-left corner). I need to pull out pictures from Facebook albums, and usually they are too large.

I know that it is possible to reduce the image before crop, but then deteriorates the quality.

By the way, looks like there is way to make this, because in jCrop preview thumbnail looks fine even if i 'dynamically' change size of image in css. Just preview! Completed cropped image is not correct, as I said there would be the upper left corner of the image.

Comment: CSS doesn't "crop" images - it can obscure parts of one with overflow:hidden inside reduced-size containers.

Comment: yes yes i know, sorry for my english =(
i didn't mean crop in css, just reduce VIEW to make it more comfortable

it will useful in case of too large image what we want to crop (for example 4.000px x 4.000 px)

Comment: `img { width: 400px; height: 400px }` would do the trick, but quality would be browser dependent.

Comment: yeap, that's what i told before, if i did this trick - image croppers begin to calculate the wrong coordinates for circumcision.  
    
ok, my question is: how to crop large image (about 2.000pixels at 2.000pixels) without loss of image quality?

Comment: crop = physically removing outer edges of an image. e.g. taking scissors and cutting off parts of a printed picture. What you're after is resizing/scaling, which keeps all the "look" of the image but reduces the total number of pixels. By definition resizing also reduces quality, since you're reducing pixel count.

Comment: crop script = http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop

Comment: imagine now that we're trying to crop huge image (bigger than in sample x5), what should we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was: divide the original image size to "smaller in the css" size. 
We obtain the coefficient, before sending it to crop - multiply x1, y1, height, width to this coefficient. profit!

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a  responsive or fluid image cropper (that adapts to the screen) you should try [Guillotine](//github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine), check out the [demo](//matiasgagliano.github.io/guillotine) and resize the browser's window to see how it adapts.